# Cannot bind to port > 1007?

Tags: ipv4, daemon, bindings

I want to bind a server to port 1023.
If I specify any free port > 1007, I have a "address already in use" error, but it works for ports <= 1007.
Working as root on Debian 7.8...

Any idea??

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does netstat -l show?  Are you really sure it's free?

Comment: @Matt I'm positive it's free (unless I have a rootkit on all ports above 1007), I've tested a bunch of random ports which don't appear binded with netstat.

Comment: Are you sure the process is starting as root?  or hasn't demoted itself before binding?

Comment: Can you try binding a high port like 65530 ?  you said "all above", if this were true you couldn't also ssh out etc.

Comment: @Matt if it was demoted it wouldn't be able to bind to port 1006, for example, would it?

Comment: @Matt good point I can bind to anything >= 1024, so it's really the range 1008-1023 which is "unbindable"...

Comment: Note: I'm working with IPv4 only

Comment: Try running 'netstat -tulpn' as root to see what process might be using that range of ports.  My guess is, another process is using those ports for real.

Comment: @Matt you're correct but these connection are ESTABLISHED and don't show on "netstat -tulpn", I had to use "netstat -tupan" to find them... silly me!

Answer (score 0):

Ports below 1024 are considered system ports and require supervisor privileges to use. To avoid a port conflict you should use a non reserved port above 1024.

To see if there is a service already using the port address, perform the following command:

```
netstat -lntu
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports

Comment: I'm root so I have supervisors privileges. Furthermore the boundary is not 1024 it's 1007 and it's the other way round: I CAN bind BELOW 1007 and I CANNOT bind ABOVE 1007.

Comment: See statement in question:  "Working as root"

Answer (score 0):

OK I found it, a process was actually using all these ports but not in a daemon way (not LISTENing). Not really clean from the developer :(

Thanks for your help